# Show that $H$ is isomorphic to the multiplicative group of positive rational numbers.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

> Consider the group $H$ of all sequences of integers $(a_1, a_2, ...)$ such that only finitely many $a_i$ are different from $0$ (and $(0, 0, 0, . . .) \in H$) under $(a_1, a_2, . . .) + (b_1, b_2, . . .) = (a_1 + b_1, a_2 +
> b_2, . . .)$. Show that $H$ is isomorphic to the multiplicative group of positive rational numbers.

At first I thought of using the idea that we can define a fraction $a/b$ as an ordered pair of integers $(a,b)$, but I have not been able to fit it with the given conditions. Any help I would appreciate

Comment: Hint: use unique factorization.

Comment: @KentaS I think I follow you. Every rational number $q$ can be written as  $q=up_{1}^{a_1}\cdots p_{n} ^{a_{n}} $ where $a_i$ is an integer. Could I send these sequences $(a_1,a_2,...)$ as exponents of these decompositions?

Comment: Yes. Also notice that we may let $u=1$, since $q$ is assumed to be positive.

Comment: @KentaS About notation, Can I define $\alpha$ via $\alpha((a_1,...,a_n,...)) =p_{1}^{a_1}...p_{n}^{a_n}$?

Comment: Yes, that seems fine if $a_n$ is the last nonzero term.